# Images as Planes, can not see the image on the plane

Tags: modeling

How do I import a *.gif though gimp, onto a plane, in blender. Once I import the image file onto a plane, how do see the image on the plane.

Comment: As far as I know gifs are not supported on Blender anymore. Try converting your image to a supported format. Check http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Data_System/Files/Formats

Answer (score 3):

Blender does not support .GIF files you could e.g. export to [.PNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) from *Gimp* (PNG has also lossless compression and transparency) For all available formats see [Formats](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Data_System/Files/Formats).

The easiest way is to enable the *Import Images as Planes* addon. You find it in the menu: *File / User Preferences*.

[image]

After enabling use *File / Import / Images as Planes*

To see the texture you need to set the viewports shading mode to *Texture*:

[image]

Behind the scenes the addon has created a plane added a material with an image texture you can check this in the materials properties:

[image]

Note: For best performance the dimension of a texture should be a [power of 2](http://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/textures/make-better-textures-correct-size-and-power-of-two.php) (128x128px, 256x256px etc.)

Answer (score 1):

This setup has worked well for me.  I think the image has all the requirements outlined.[image]

In past versions of Blender, using "Textured Solid" had a huge viewport performance hit when working with high geometry counts but this seems to have been fixed for recent builds.

Also, you can also just drop and drag a UV mapped image from your HD folder onto the model to see what it looks like without having to go through all the trouble of loading the texture in as a material asset.  This is very useful when baking.  Also, baked textures usually update in this view automatically.  (I say 'usually' because using *Undo* will sometimes cause Blender to hold onto the old texture.)  You can fix this using the UV Editor to save the image and then activate the 'refresh' button for that texture, now the 3D Viewport will update the texture to the current version.

[image]